# How to set device update agent as identity module to work with identity service?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-identity, azure-iot-hub-device-update

I've set my device from test environment to run device update agent as a identity module. I copied primary connection string from my device identity module from iothub and set it on my device du-config.json. It worked, I can see the identity module as connected.

Now I see for production scenarios I should use identity service for device provisioning. I've installed it on my device and now I need to edit config.toml to set connection properties. For now, all I have is my device connection string and my agent as module identity connection string, but I'm not sure which one to use on identity service connection_string under source = "manual". The module Identity connection string gives me errors, so I guess device connection should be the correct one.

But even using device connection string on config.toml from identity service and erasing my module identity connection string from the du-config.json and setting property "connection type" from string to AIS, my agent module identity does not come connected, I'm not sure how the module will be found since there is no module identity connection set anywhere. In the device update agent logs I see:

```
[E] Invalid connection info. [HealthCheck]
[E] Agent health check failed. [main]
[D] Log file created: /var/log/adu/du-agent.20231009-150417.log [zlog_init]
[I] Agent (linux; 1.0.2) starting. [main]
[I] Git Info: HEAD:2d1f0367 [main]
[I] Supported Update Manifest version: min: 4, max: 5 [main]
Error: Time:Mon Oct  9 17:04:17 2023 File:/tmp/azure-iot-sdk-c/c-utility/adapters/socketio_berkeley.c Func:initiate_socket_connection Line:353 Failure: connect failure 13.
Error: Time:Mon Oct  9 17:04:17 2023 File:/tmp/azure-iot-sdk-c/c-utility/adapters/socketio_berkeley.c Func:socketio_open Line:829 lookup_address_and_connect_socket failed
Error: Time:Mon Oct  9 17:04:17 2023 File:/tmp/azure-iot-sdk-c/deps/uhttp/src/uhttp.c Func:uhttp_client_open Line:1134 opening xio failed
[I] Failed to provision a connection string from eis, Failed with error EISErr_ConnErr on service EISService_IdentityService [GetConnectionInfoFromIdentityService]
```

Can you please clarify what I am missing, please?

Comment: Could please the share reference you used i.e MS-DOS, git etc to configure

Comment: What you mean? My device runs a Ubuntu 18.04. After installing both applications and dependencies, for the configuration I've only edited files du-config.json from device update and config.toml from identity service as I described.

Comment: Hope this reference [helps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-agent-provisioning)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I've following these pages instructions to install and set up device update agent and for installing identity service. My question is which connection string should I use on identity service (I know there are a lot of connection setup attributes on config.toml, but I want to use connection string for now) and how it finds my module identity update device agent (since I will clear it's connection string from du-config.json).

Comment: you should use the device connection string on `config.toml` from identity service and erase the module identity connection string from the `du-config.json`

Comment: Hope this reference [helps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-simulator)

Comment: Thanks. I still got the same errors but from your last link, all I could find different from what I did is: "You can also use the IoT Identity Service to provision the device. To do, that install the iot indentity service before installing the Device Update agent.". So I will try to set up a new VM installing AIS first, then ADU. For me it is a bit strange having to install things in a specific order, and also not finding this information on the tutorial beginning.

Comment: I've set a new Ubuntu VM, installed IoT Identity Service before device update agent and it worked. Also, on my first try doing this I had an error with do-client, something related to nested scenarios. Solution was after installing ADU dependencies, I cloned do-client repository, build and install it's debian package. After that, built and installed ADU, edited to use AIS and it worked. For those who don't know what happens, after setting everything up, on AIS service start, it creates an device update agent module identity named "IoTHubDeviceUpdate" that is the device ADU agent.

Answer (score 0):

To set the device update agent as an identity module to work with the identity service, you need to edit the configuration file for Device Update by running the command [below](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-agent-provisioning.md) :

```
sudo nano /etc/adu/du-config.json
```

Change the connection type to "AIS" for agents who will be using the IoT Identity Service for provisioning. The ConnectionData field must be an empty string.

Note: All values with the 'Place value here' tag must be set. See Configuring a DU [agent](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-agent-provisioning.md).
you  should use the device connection string on `config.toml` from the identity service and erase the module identity connection string from the [du-config.json](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-agent-provisioning.md).

[image]

If you are using the IoT [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-simulator) service to provision the device, you can configure the Device Update agent with "connectionType": "AIS" and connectionData as a blank string in the configuration [file](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-simulator.md).